# Remove duplicates between different array dimensions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a table in the database with navbar menu items, this table has a relationship 1xN with itself, I'm retrieving the data (like: `\App\Menu::with(['childs'])->get()`) as:

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'id_parent' => NULL,
        'url' => '/',
        'childs' => array ()
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'id_parent' => NULL,
        'url' => '/blog',
        'childs' => array (
            array(
                'id' => 3,
                'id_parent' => 2,
                'url' => 'blog/kitchen',
                'childs' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 4,
                        'id_parent' => 3,
                        'url' => 'blog/kitchen/salads',
                        'childs' => array()
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 5,
                        'id_parent' => 3,
                        'url' => 'blog/kitchen/soups',
                        'childs' => array()
                    ),
                )
            ),
        )
    ), 
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'id_parent' => 2,
        'url' => '/blog/kitchen',
        'childs' => array()
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'id_parent' => 3,
        'url' => 'blog/kitchen/salads',
        'childs' => array()
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'id_parent' => 3,
        'url' => 'blog/kitchen/soups',
        'childs' => array()
    ),
);
```

What I need:

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'id_parent' => NULL,
        'url' => '/',
        'childs' => array ()
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'id_parent' => NULL,
        'url' => '/blog',
        'childs' => array (
            array(
                'id' => 3,
                'id_parent' => 2,
                'url' => 'blog/kitchen',
                'childs' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 4,
                        'id_parent' => 3,
                        'url' => 'blog/kitchen/salads',
                        'childs' => array()
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 5,
                        'id_parent' => 3,
                        'url' => 'blog/kitchen/soups',
                        'childs' => array()
                    ),
                )
            ),
        )
    ),
);
```

If there is an easier way, like; `SELECT` directly in the database it would be great, if not, just removing the inner items from the outer layer with PHP is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try below query.

```
\App\Menu::where('id_parent', '=', null)->with(['childs'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

he will ecrase the `/` url if he filters through null `parent_id`

Here is an example of solution using only PHP

```
// an empty array
$arr = array();
// data you import from the database
$array = \App\Menu::where('id_parent', '=', null)
                   ->with(['childs'])->toArray();

// populate the empty array
$arr[] = array_shift($array);
$arr[] = array_shift($array);
```

the `$array` variable contain the 3 last undesired occurrences, while the `$arr` variable contain your desired values.

But I'm not suggesting to you that because you can do it with **another way** using [Collections](http://laravel.com/docs/collections#available-methods)

Answer (score 0):

use this one time.......i think this will help you

```php
\App\Menu::where('id_parent', '=', null)->with(['childs'])->get();
```

Comment: Hi Lokesh, thanks for your answer! Would you please consider explaining a bit more about your code, and why it works?